# built in Soap extension php5 passing in params as associative array

Tags: php

I have this xml I'm wanting to pass to this web service function

```
<UserName>myuser</UserName> 
<Password>password</Password> 
<User>
    <AddCoverCode />
    <title>sdadasdsa</title>
</User>
</CreateNewUser>','',array(),'document', 'literal');
```

I'm using the soap extension buit in php5.

Is this what I'm supposed to be passing in the soapcall function as parameters?

```
array('CreateNewUser' => array(
    'UserName' =>  'sc', 
    'Password' =>  'i82372',
    'Registration' =>   array('username' =>'new','password' =>'ss'));
```

Comment: I hope that's not a real password from a real service.

Comment: I had a similar problem. take a look at my answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803688/barnes-and-noble-seller-soap-api-using-php/3830405#3830405

Answer (score 0):

```
$client = new SoapClient($url);

$params = array( 'UserName' => 'sc', 'Password' => 'i82372', 'Registration' => array('username' =>'new','password' =>'ss' );

$res = $client->createUser($params);
```